# Resolve to n in net present value formula

Tags: polynomials, exponential-function, exponentiation

There is the formula for the *net present value* which consists of a few variables and also of exponents.

Resolving to $K$, $C$, and $A_0$ is fairly simple.
But is there a possibility to resolve to / solve for $n$?

The net present value formula:

$$K=-A_0+C\frac{(1+i)^n-1}{i(1+i)^n}$$

Comment: By "resolve," do you mean "solve for..."?

Comment: Yes, exactly. I updated the above posting accordingly.

Comment: It's a bit of juggling but it can be done. Now to write a solution before someone beats me to it.

Answer (score 0):

We'll use the fact that $\frac{x-1}{x} = 1 - \frac{1}{x}$ (it's just long division). Let's begin.

First add $A_0$ to both sides.

$$ K + A_0=C\frac{(1+i)^n-1}{i(1+i)^n} $$

Now multiply both sides by $\frac{i}{C}$.

$$ \frac{i}{C}(K + A_0)=\frac{(1+i)^n-1}{(1+i)^n} $$

Use the fact I mentioned at the start to break the fraction apart.

$$  \frac{i}{C}(K + A_0) = 1 - \frac{1}{(1+i)^n} $$

Now for three steps in one - subtract 1, multiply by -1, and take reciprocals.

$$ \left(1 - \frac{i}{C}(K + A_0)\right)^{-1} = (1+i)^n $$

Now for the final step. Take natural logarithms (or any log, doesn't matter), and do a last division. This gives

$$ \ln \left( \left(1 - \frac{i}{C}(K + A_0)\right)^{-1} \right) = n \ln (1+i) $$

or, simply

$$ \boxed{-\frac{ \ln \left(1 - \frac{i}{C}(K + A_0)\right)}{\ln (1+i)} = n.}$$

Note the minus sign out front, because of logarithm properties.